# Unit test does not pass when error is thrown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have the following JS class:

```
class MyDispatcher {

  subscribe(eventName, handler) {

    if (typeof eventName !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('eventName must be a string');
    }

   //some other code
  }

}
```

I have this Jest unit test for it:

```
test('Non string event fails', () => {
    expect(MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')).toThrow();
});
```

The problem is that when I run the test, it fails with this error:

```
● myDispatcher › Non string event fails

    eventName must be a string

      at MyDispatcher.subscribe (src/modules/MyDispatcher.js:10:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/__tests__/MyDispatcherTest.js:26:31)
```

I can't understand why the test fails. The method throws an error, which is exactly what I'm testing for. Therefore, the test should pass, right?

I tried also this test:

```
expect(MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')).toThrowError('eventName must be a string');
```

and this test:

```
expect(MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')).toThrow(new Error('eventName must be a string'));
```

However, they both fail with the same error message.

Any idea why these tests fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')` function call is throwing an exception before even executing the actual test, replace

```
expect(MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')).toThrow();
```

with

```
expect(() => MyDispatcher.subscribe(3, 'myHandler')).toThrow();
```

Comment: That's the point. I want the input to be wrong, so I can throw an error.